# Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Internet Explorer CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-ce

Something strange seems to be happening with IE on Windows Embedded CE 6.0 that I can't explain.  I have tag in my page something like this:

```
<LINK href="~/getStyleSheet.aspx" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When I open this page on the device the page looks totally wrong (like it doesn't have any styling).  After some fiddling around I changed it to be:

```
<LINK href="~/getStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And just created a static .css file with the appropriate contents.  That made it worked.

So it seems that IE is ignoring styling if it doesn't come from a file with a .css extension.  Any one have any thoughts on this?  Is this by design?  Is there a way around this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is related to HTTP headers.  I narrowed it down to the Cache-Control header.  When it is `Cache-Control: no-cache` the CSS doesn't get applied.  If it is `Cache-Control: private` then the CSS does get applied.